# How can I reinstall android 4.2 after having updated to 4.4?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, downgrade

I just updated my nexus4 to kitkat 4.4. Play services seems to drain the
battery. Thus I would like to move back to 4.2. Is it possible? And how can
I do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Kitkat 4.4 or Jelly Bean 4.3? Even if the procedure is most likely the same, you must choose...

Answer (score 1):

Which version is your Nexus 4 running on?

**4.4 (KRT16S)** or **4.4.2 (KOT49H)**

Check by going into `Settings > About > Build Number`

**4.4.2 (KOT49H)** is newer and fixes a lot of the bugs from **4.4 (KRT16S)**. You might try updating if you are running a lower version.

---

You can revert back to **4.2.2 (JDQ39)** via:

- **factory reset**
- **manual flash** (stock image [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occam))
- **a system backup image**

As for the Google Play Services battery drain: AFAIK it is caused by Google Now always accessing your location reporter and also waking up the phone from time to time.

Known solutions:

- disable the location reporter or prevent Google Now from accessing your location
- turn off High Accuracy when location reporting (GPS) is not in use
- simply turn Google Now off

One more thing to take into concern are the updates. Have you updated all the stock Google apps. If not, just leave your Nexus on wifi for a while to update all the Google goodies and then try using it for a while on KitKat. If you notice the battery drain again revert back to Jelly Bean or simply try applying a solution from above to see if it fixes the drain.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not created a system backup (sometimes called nandroid) before updating, you have only one option: Install an Android 4.2 through recovery or flash and then do a factory reset.